# Using Require.js with Trigger.io

Tags: requirejs, trigger.io

I just started using Trigger.io and am building a movie mobile app using backbone.js and require.js but without much success.

My project scaffold is generated by Grunt-BBB.

It runs fine when it's built and run as a web app ("forge build web", & then "forge run web"), but unfortunately, it fails to load the JS files when it's built and run as iOS or Android.  I've looked through the demo Backbone.js example, but it's not using Require.js.

I realize that Require.js is async in nature and that might be the root cause of it not working when running on the mobile.

Any alternative to Require.js or work-around to get Require.js working with Trigger.io will be appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had a go with Require.js in a Trigger.io app and it seems to be working fine on both iOS and Android. I don't have an app setup with Grunt-BBB so I haven't tested that.

When running on Android you should see any Javascript errors that occur in the log output, do you see any, and if so are they at all helpful?

Otherwise if you could zip up the src folder of the app you are trying to build and send it to support@trigger.io we can take a more detailed look at what is going wrong.